# Volatile field in Singleton class in Java

Tags: java, singleton, volatile

In some sites/blogs, I have found Singleton code as

```
public class MySingleton{

    private static MySingleton instance = null;
    .......
    .......
}
```

and in some other, I have found Singleton code as

```
public class MySingleton{

    private volatile static MySingleton instance = null;
    .......
    .......
}
```

Is it necessary to make `MySingleton` reference as `volatile`? Will it be of any significance?

Comment: I recommend you this article: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl

Answer (score 1):

Volatile keyword in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory

** Edit **

```
private volatile static MySingleton instance = null;
```

In above code snippet the volatile keyword ensures that multiple threads handle the `instance` variable correctly when it is being initialized to the MySingleton instance.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz2BYyA5Jnm

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, if it is mutable and appears in multithreaded code.  You just need to learn what `volatile` means, there's nothing special about whether a singleton will require its use.

Comment: In case of multi-threaded environment, we synchronize the method or use synchronized block which returns the Singleton..so what is the need of volatile?

Comment: @djechlin if the getter that gives access to that field uses a form of synchronization, volatile is not required.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell - the fields are private in both examples, so depending on how they are pusblished, you might or might not need them to be volatile. The standard idiom is [to use an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831737/why-is-enum-best-implementation-for-singleton) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Either you want to keep things simple with an `enum`

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE
}
```

Or you have a good reason to make it more complicated

```
public class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton() { }

    private static MySingleton instance = null;

    public synchronized static MySingleton getInstance() {
         if (instance == null)
             instance = new MySingleton();
         return instance;
    }
}
```

Either way, using volatile doesn't help.

IMHO, There isn't a good *Singleton* pattern where you would use `volatile` so if it is needed, the code need fixing or simplifying.

---

AFAIK the only case where you would use volatile is for double-checked locking

```
public class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton() { }

    private static volatile MySingleton instance = null;

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
         if (instance == null)
             synchronzied(MySingleton.class) {
                 if (instance == null)
                     instance = new MySingleton();
             }
         return instance;
    }
}
```

For comparison, the `enum` example above does much the sample thing.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: *"There isn't a good pattern where you would use volatile"* is maybe a bit strong, unless you meant a good *singleton* pattern.

Comment: @assylias You are right, but of the many patterns for singleton, AFAIK only double-checked locking uses volatile and while it is no longer buggy it is needlessly complicated.

Comment: I initially read it as don't use volatile (at all) - when you meant don't use volatile when writing a singleton. ;-)

Comment: @assylias There are uses for volatile,  but not in most Singleton patterns. (e.g. a flag to stop a thread should be `volatile`)

Answer (score 0):

This is only necessary if you have a mutable singleton field in a multi-threaded system, particularly in situations where the singleton is lazily initialized.

This is part of a larger discussion of how to lazily initialize singletons in multi-threaded systems in Java. There are several mechanisms that are used for this, but the most popular are:

- [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)
- Double-checked locking using `volatile`
- [Static inner "instance holder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)
- [Declaring the singleton as an `enum` instead of a `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635396/pattern-for-lazy-thread-safe-singleton-instantiation-in-java/3635619#3635619)

The currently accepted method of holding lazily initialized singletons for a multi-threaded system is the `enum` approach, though all 4 of them work in Java 1.5+.

Comment: For lazy initialization? Can you cite that? Most IDE's use the holder idiom for their singleton templates.

Comment: The singleton won't be initialised until the enum class is loaded. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7790749/829571 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635619/829571

Comment: Fair enough, I just have one concern. What about `public static` variables or methods, independent of the singleton's initialization, that are in the singleton's class? When accessing a static method or field of the enum, the instance would be loaded, which wouldn't happen with the holder idiom, which *only* initializes when `getInstance` is called. They'd have to be refactored into a separate class (which isn't necessarily a bad thing). Beyond that, I definitely see your point, and I'll update my answer and add this pattern to my toolbelt, thanks :)