# Differences between two singleton examples

Tags: java, singleton, instance

Class A 1

```
public class A {

    private static final A instance = new A();

    public static A getInstance() {
        return new A();
    }

}
```

Class A 2

```
public class A {

    private static final A instance = new A();
    private A(){}
    public static A getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

I just start to learn singleton and I saw two java examples that using class A 1 example and class A 2 example. Is the class A 1 `getInstance()` is singleton? I also like to know what is the differences between these two class A `getInstance()` method? Thank you

Comment: First returns unnamed object that is different then `instance` object, whereas second code returns same object `instance` that is class level object (static).

Comment: "I just start to learn singleton" please stop where you are. Singletons are an almost-anti pattern and most of the times not the solution you want, especially if it has an internal state, like `String status`.

Comment: I suggest you use a simple enum Singleton `class A { INSTANCE; private String status; }` You only need to add  methods for the status.

Comment: Edited please check Class A 2

Comment: @gjman2 The class should be final and the instance field should be final.

Comment: Personally I only use stateless singletons if I can help it.  Singletons with state are very difficult to test.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You wrote `class A` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In A1, `A` is not [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).. `getInstance()` is returning a new instance of `A` everytime

In A2, `A` is **not singleton** again, cause the **default constructor** is still `public` (implicitly) . One can easily create more instances from outside

**EDIT:**

Since you have edited the class `A` in A2, now it becomes singleton.

Here `A` is created eagerly and will be thread-safe by default. Check [lazy vs eager intialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790185/singleton-lazy-vs-eager-instantiation)

Comment: @gjman2 The class is not final and the instance field is not final.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for helping me out. Guys, One of the benefit of singleton is to prevent from creating unnecessary objects right?

Answer (score 1):

> I also like to know what is the differences between these two class A getInstance() method

**Class A 1:**

If you look at the code :

```
 public static A getInstance() {
    return new A();
}
```

You are returning a new instance of `A` on each call of `getInstance()` method and hence it is not a Singleton. Also you have not made the default constructor `private` in this case and any code outside your class can easily create instances of the class breaking the Singleton paradigm.

**Class A 2:**

Looking at this code :

```
public class A {

  private static final A instance = new A();
  private A(){}
  public static A getInstance() {
     return instance;
  }
}
```

You are returning the same instance for each call of `getInstance()`.Now your class behaves like Singleton , You are actually doing an eager instantiation of the Singleton instance here and this Singleton instance should be thread-safe. Also make the class `final` so that no one can sub class it and break the Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

**In first case**

> each time a new instance of `A` is creating .

**in second case **

As per single ton pattern ,it should be

```
public class A {
   private static A instance = null;
   private  A() {

   }
   public static A getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new A();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

> The class `A` maintains a static reference to the lone singleton instance and returns that reference from the static getInstance() method.

Answer (score 0):

*Is the class A 1 getInstance() is singleton?*

No because everytime you are calling this method, a new instance of `A` is created.

*I also like to know what is the differences between these two class A getInstance() method?*

The first `getInstance()` will always create a new instance of class A, the second `getInstance()` will always return the same instance created of class A.

Answer (score 0):

```
        There are two ways of creating a singleton class
        1, Dynamic Singleton
        2, Static Singleton

        Static Singleton :

        public class A {
          //Create a object of class A and make it final so that nobody can modify it
          private static final A instance = new A();

          //make the constructor private so that new objects can not be created
          private A(){}

          //provide a method to access the object
          public static A getInstance() {
             return instance;
          }
        }

        Dynamic Singleton :

a, Single Check
        public class A {
    //Create a object reference of class A
    private static A instance = null;

    //make the constructor private so that new objects can not be created
    private  A() {}


    public static A getInstance() {
        //check if instance is null or not
        if(instance == null) {
            if(instance == null) {
                //if null then create an instance of class A and assign it to the final reference
                instance = new A();
            }

        }
        return instance;
    }
}

b, double check
public class A {
    //Create a object reference of class A
    private static A instance = null;

    //make the constructor private so that new objects can not be created
    private  A() {}


    public static A getInstance() {
        //check if instance is null or not
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(A.class){
                //Double Check
                if(instance == null) {
                    //if null then create an instance of class A and assign it to the final reference
                    instance = new A();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```